# Merge [turing] and [turing-machines]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

The [turing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/turing) and [turing-machines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/turing-machines) tags seem to be about the seem topic. How about we merge them?

Comment: I see [tag:turing-complete] and [tag:turning-machines] in there, though the wiki is definitely aiming for [tag:turning-machines].

Comment: There's also a turing-test question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1648670/feasibility-of-beating-the-turing-test-with-modern-software And someone thinks it's a language: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2018414/need-help-with-counted-loops-in-turing

Comment: Yup, [Turing is a language as well](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_%28programming_language%29). With only 31 questions it'd be easier just to retag them all and burninate it.

Comment: @KevinBrown: I guess we might need [tag:turing-lang] then.

Comment: Logically, the two tags do make sense. Turing made many contributions to computing, of which the Turing machine is particularly important. If we are going to get rid of one of the tags, it should be the more specialized one.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan [tag:turing] seems way too unclear to me—just look at the variety of topics the questions still tagged with it covers. If anything, we should add more specialized tags to retag them with.

Comment: There were 32 questions in [tag:turing] (recreated again), took care of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There were 33 questions tagged [turing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/turing) when I started. [turing-machines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/turing-machines) fit most of them; [turing-lang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/turing-lang) and [turing-complete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/turing-complete) fit a couple; some of the rest had the tag removed. **There are no remaining questions with the tag.**

This question is about the Turing Test:

- <strike>[Feasibility of beating the Turing Test with modern software?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1648670)</strike> ([untagged](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/1648670/3))

These questions didn't seem to be about Turing anything:

- <strike>[language over {1} which is recognizable but not decidable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13672850)</strike> ([untagged](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/13672850/5))
- <strike>[How to determine which class these languages belong to?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13906540)</strike> ([retagged](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/13906540/2) [turing-machines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/turing-machines))
- <strike>[What's a non-deterministic procedure?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17502337)</strike> ([untagged](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/17502337/2))

This one relates to Alan Turing:

- <strike>[Turing's solution to the Entscheidungsproblem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29199281)</strike> ([untagged](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/29199281/2))

---

[image: This tag has been burninated.]

Comment: Questions about recognizability, decidability, Turing completeness and language class are very closely related to Turing machines. Each of those concepts is ultimately defined in terms of whether there exists a Turing machine with certain properties.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan Thanks for the tip! I think I also went through these too quickly; I'll have another look.

Comment: I went ahead and created the turing-lang tag http://stackoverflow.com/tags/turing-lang/info  will change the turing info to show that it is deprecated

Comment: Actually, it's not ready for burnination. That would imply that there are a lot of questions left where the only thing wrong with them is them having the bad tag (they just have to loose it, not gain any others), and now a community manager should nuke it from orbit. Instead, it is burninated, as there are no questions left, congratulations. The unused tag will be pruned at 3:00 automatically.

Comment: @Deduplicator Awww, but I wanted to send out the signal!